# Java script window.print() with the specific given URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I created the report in my View of my asp.net mvc 2.0, and then I want to use link or button to print out that view. But in the view include the header, footer and also the content that is the result from searching for each record. I want to let the user see what they are want to print in my view, and after that they can click Print.

I'm using this  :

```
function printChart() {
  var URL = "EvaluatingReport";
  var W = window.open(URL);
  W.window.print();
}
```

But it is open the URL again. Could any one tell me how to specify the URL to `window.print()` ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: On which page is the Print button?

Comment: The page that list all the result.

Comment: So why can't the Print button on that page just use `window.print()`?

Comment: I can print Neil, But I just don't want to include the header, footer and some element in that page. So I have one solution, when click on `window.print()` button, and then call another page that is contain the element in the old page but not include the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a print stylesheet that hides the elements that you don't want printed.

This and other suggestions are also available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing).